# Upper-bouding $||A||_2$ with $||A_i||_2$, where $A_i$ are rows of $A$

Tags: normed-spaces

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix and $A_i$ be its $i$-th row. We know $||A_i||_2 \le c_i$ for each $i$, that is, the upper bound for each row. Now we want an upper bound for $||A||_2$ using the $c_i$'s we know.

Since $||A_i||_{1} \le \sqrt{n}||A_i||_2 \le \sqrt{n} c_i$ and $||A||_{\infty} = \max_{i} \{||A_i||_1\} \le \sqrt{n} \max_i \{c_i\}$, we have $||A||_2 \le \sqrt{n} ||A||_{\infty} \le n  \max_i \{c_i\}$. However, this idea is naive and tortuous. I am afraid this bound is too lose and looking for a better bound.

Otherwise, if this bound $||A||_2 \le n \max_i \{||A_i||_2\}$ is tight enough, please provide an example such that the equality holds.

All norms are operator norms.

Comment: What is $\|A\|_2$ here? The operator norm, or Hilbert–Schmidt ($(\sum_{ij} |a_{ij}|^2)^{1/2}$)?

Comment: It means operator norm here.

Comment: Okay. Then this problem is fairly standard fare, to be found in many textbooks. I wrote up an answer for you, since actually *finding* this in a textbook would be more work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a vector $x$ and $y=Ax$, you have $y_i=A_ix$. That is really an inner product, so Cauchy–Schwarz gives you $\lvert y_i\rvert\le\lVert A_i\rVert_2\lVert x\rVert_2$. Squaring and summing, we get $\lVert y\rVert_2^2\le\sum_{i=1}^n\lVert A_i\rVert_2^2\lVert x\rVert_2^2$, and therefore $\lVert A\rVert_2^2\le\sum_{i=1}^n\lVert A_i\rVert_2^2\le\sum_{i=1}^nc_i^2$.

This inequality is sharp, for you can pick $A$ to be a rank one matrix, i.e., all rows are parallel, and then you can pick $x$ parallel to the rows, so you get equality in the application of Cauchy–Schwarz.